# WP REST API V2 Issue In [posts_per_page]=-1

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api

Hi i am using using Plugin WP REST API V2 in which after host change getting issue the filter  [posts_per_page]=-1 stop working i am only getting 10 posts of custom post
please help me 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

The ability to set `posts_per_page=-1` obviously was a bug:

- https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2759
- https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2357

So you have to set a limit yourself.

Comment: Thank you for answer
Got your point but for example i am having 101 or some more posts so what i gona do for that 
now i am using ?per_page=100
its working fine getting 100 posts
please let me know thank you

Comment: Personally i don't use this API, but there must be a function or a response parameter that tell you how much posts exists so you can calculate the pages and paginate yourself. There must be a page parameter where you can request next next pages.

Comment: f.e. 101 posts / 100 posts_per_page = 1.01 => 2 pages

Comment: Also could it be that there is a calculated pagination in the response